# Weblogic 10.3.3.0 application debugging with eclipse

Tags: eclipse, remote-debugging, weblogic-10.x

Hello I saw some 11g tutorials with a Google search:

http://saltnlight5.blogspot.com/2014/04/how-to-setup-remote-debug-with-weblogic.html

http://java.dzone.com/articles/how-setup-remote-debug

They both specify adding something like:
JAVA_OPTIONS="$JAVA_OPTIONS -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=y"

Two questions I have is:

One, at my work we have domains/domainName/bin/setDomainEnv.sh and in the same "domainName" directory another folder called servers, with a bunch of our servers on it. I am not an expert in infrastructure but I am looking for a way to remotely debug an application on Weblogic through Eclipse that is located on one of the servers. What is the best way to sync up the one server and its application with Eclipse rather than effecting all of the severs (unless I am misunderstanding).

Second, is there not a way to set this up through the Weblogic Administration Console? I tried looking around for anything intuitive, but nothing stood out.

Comment: Why down vote me? At least give me the courtesy to say why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are starting your servers with NodeManager, you should be able to add the arguments to "Arguments" in the Weblogic Admin Console under:

> Environment -> Servers -> Your Server -> Configuration (tab) -> Server Start (sub-tab)

Comment: Okay, thank you. I added the arguments and keep getting a failed_not_restartable error on the server.
Is there a specific format for this adding it to the arguments section?

I tried:
-JAVA_OPTIONS=$JAVA_OPTIONS -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=n
beneath the DXL.HomeDir declaration.

Comment: Get rid of JAVA_OPTIONS=$JAVA_OPTIONS part

Comment: Have you tried what I mentioned? The whole `JAVA_DEBUG` section is a standard part of `setDomainEnv` - you shouldn't need to change it unless you want a different port

Comment: Yes I just tried your suggestion but get a, "Failed to connect to remote VM. Connection refused.
Connection refused: connect"  Error so I will need to further troubleshoot why.

Comment: Yosef, going with your answer, for the listening port, do I use the one set to the application? Or would I use a different one for the debugging port?

Comment: Different port. There should be a standard one for remote debugging.

Answer (score 0):

`setDomainEnv` - set `debugFlag="true"` and every server you start will listen on the port specified, allowing remote debug connections.
Inside of Eclipse, select, `Run > Debug Configuration` and then select `Remote Java Application` Choose the host your server runs on with the port from `setDomainEnv`

- This will affect all servers, so if you have two running on the same host you will have a port conflict. You can do something simple like putting an `if` statement into `setDomainEnv` so the debug is only turned on for a specific `SERVER_NAME`

`<domain>/servers` - this is the folder where weblogic caches security information, application information, startup params, etc for each server. You shouldn't be manipulating this directly on the file system

Another thing that may be of interest to you it the [Oracle Enterprise Pack for Eclipse (OEPE)](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/eclipse/overview/index.html). It allows you to start/stop servers directly from Eclipse as well as additional debug support.

Sample from my `setDomainEnv.sh`:

```
debugFlag="true"
export debugFlag
JAVA_DEBUG=""
export JAVA_DEBUG

if [ "${debugFlag}" = "true" ] ; then
    JAVA_DEBUG="-Xdebug -Xnoagent -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8453,server=y,suspend=n -Djava.compiler=NONE"
    export JAVA_DEBUG

    JAVA_OPTIONS="${JAVA_OPTIONS} ${enableHotswapFlag} -ea -da:com.bea... -da:javelin... -da:weblogic... -ea:com.bea.wli... -ea:com.bea.broker... -ea:com.bea.sbconsole..."
    export JAVA_OPTIONS
fi
```