# How to remote debug an enterprise application running on web logic server in eclipse IDE(same machine)

Tags: java, eclipse, weblogic, remote-debugging, eclipse-juno

I am new to weblogic application server and remote debugging & have gone through several post to set up remote debugging.
 Some post suggest to edit **setDomainEnv.cmd** file while others suggest to edit **startWeblogic.cmd** file in my **WEBLOGIC_HOME\user_projects\domains\my_domain\bin**.
But neither of the solutions worked for me. Listed below are solutions which I tried :

1) Edit setDomainEnv.cmd file

```
set JAVA_DEBUG=-Xdebug -Xnoagent -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=%DEBUG_PORT%,server=y,suspend=n -Djava.compiler=NONE
set JAVA_OPTIONS=%JAVA_OPTIONS% %enableHotswapFlag% -ea -da:com.bea... -da:javelin... -da:weblogic... -ea:com.bea.wli... -ea:com.bea.broker... -ea:com.bea.sbconsole...
```

The port number is set to 8543 in the file

```
if "%DEBUG_PORT%"=="" (
    set DEBUG_PORT=8453
)
```

2)Edit startWeblogic.cmd file

I added the following line at the top of the file

```
-Xdebug -Xnoagent -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8543,server=y,suspend=n
```

Then in eclipse,when i run debug configuration(port number : 8543), I get
 **Failed to connect to remote VM. Connection refused.
Connection refused: connect**

Please let me know 
  **1)** How **remote debugging** works?
**2)** How to set up **remote debugging in eclipse with weblogic server** ?
**3)** What is the difference between above 2 methods ?
  **4)** Where do I need to add the **debug command(-Xdebug....)** in the startWeblogic.cmd file(at the top)?
**5)** What is the purpose of **setDomainEnv.cmd file in weblogic server** ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Web logic server & eclipse are running on same machine. I have set the host as localhost

Comment: possible duplicate of [Weblogic remote debugging using eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3882203/weblogic-remote-debugging-using-eclipse)

Comment: There are at least 5+ duplicates of this question already on stack overflow. None of these worked? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3882203/weblogic-remote-debugging-using-eclipse http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18875252/eclipse-weblogic-debugging http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21113673/debug-weblogic-app-on-managed-server-on-eclipse http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28163130/weblogic-10-3-3-0-application-debugging-with-eclipse

Comment: I tried all posts but still got same error - Failed to connect to remote VM. And some posts suggest to edit startWeblogic.cmd while others suggest to edit setDomainEnv.cmd which is confusing. Can anyone please post the series of steps to be followed to set up remote debugging. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Also other posts do not answer all my questions

Comment: `setDomainEnv` already contains a line in it for `JAVA_DEBUG`. You do not need to edit startWebLogic. Check your server log file and see if it says it is listening on the debug port. set `JAVA_DEBUG=true` or `debugFlag=true` in setDomainEnv

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be sufficient to just set environment variable before starting Weblogic. Start `cmd` and before starting weblogic `set debugFlag=true`. This should make weblogic open debug port which should be set to some default like 8453. You can also `set DEBUG_PORT=8888` or any other free port, if you want to change it.

Start Weblogic and *verify* that the port has been opened. You can use tools like [cports](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/cports.html) or [ProcessExplorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/pl-pl/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) for that (or event [netstat](http://helpdeskgeek.com/windows-7/use-netstat-to-see-listening-ports-and-pid-in-windows/)).

In case debug port isn't open, check if you run Weblogic in development mode, because `debugFlag` can be ignored in production mode.

In Eclipse create a remote debug configuration (and remember that this option is not available in `Run configuration` that is next to it on the toolbar):
[image: debug config screenshot]

In point 3 on the screenshot select the project you deploy to weblogic that you want to debug.

It that does not work post the problems you have.

Comment: debugFlag is set to true in setDomainEnv.cmd file. 
Also, following line is added -- if "%debugFlag%"=="true" ( set JAVA_DEBUG=-Xdebug -Xnoagent -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=%DEBUG_PORT%,server=y,suspend=n -Djava.compiler=NONE set JAVA_OPTIONS=%JAVA_OPTIONS% %enableHotswapFlag% -ea -da:com.bea... -da:javelin... -da:weblogic... -ea:com.bea.wli... -ea:com.bea.broker... -ea:com.bea.sbconsole... ) else ( set JAVA_OPTIONS=%JAVA_OPTIONS% %enableHotswapFlag% -da ). Then in eclipse,when i run debug configuration, I get Failed to connect to remote VM. Connection refused.

Comment: What version of Weblogic do you use?

Comment: Post the contents of setDomainEnv.cmd somwhere. Can be on some external service (pastebin?).

Comment: Thanks for looking into my issue. I have not changed anything in the setDomainEnv.cmd file other than adding the 2 lines of code shown above in my post. Still should I post the contents of the file?